# Adding subview to view goes under navigation and tab bar - SWIFT

Tags: swift

When I add a subview

```
self.view.addSubview(SwiftSpinner.show("Saving", animated: true))
```

if there is a navigation bar or tab bar this view appears under these. The height seems to be set correctly so I don't understand why.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You must set the frame of the view before adding to as a subview.

If the frame origin is at (0, 0) it will show up under the nav bar because the view controller's view actually extends under the nav bar (that's how you get that nice blurring of content underneath the nav bar).

Comment: The issue I think is because I have adjust inset set to true. I tried adding the frame but still honours the top and bottom insets.